# How to add a Domain to a Feature Class in ArcGIS when the Subtype Field is Frozen?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, domains, subtype

I'm trying to add a Domain to a Field in a Feature Class in ArcGIS 10.2. 
I'm Following the Instructions found in the Official Documentation for [Associating default values and domains with tables and feature classes](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Associating_default_values_and_domains_with_tables_and_feature_classes/001s00000009000000/) 
and [Creating subtypes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005r00000003000000). The issue I'm running into is that, after successfully creating a new Domain in the Enterprise GeoDatabase containing the Feature Class of Interest, I cannot Create a Subtype in that same Feature Class. Using the Catalog navigation tree, I right-click on the Feature Class, select Properties, locate the Subtypes tab, then Attempt to Add a Subtype, in the service of Adding a Domain. The Subtype Field and Default Subtype Fields are 'greyed out'

[image: Frozen Subtypes]

**AND** whenever I try and add text to the Subtypes files, the Domain box automatically opens.  This image indicates that I have properly created a Domain prior to Engaging with this Workflow.

[image: Automatic Open]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue a while back when I transitioned into an Enterprise Level GDB.

The workaround is a bit convoluted but it gets what you need:

From your Geodatabase:
Right Click

[image]

- select Properties
- Select Domains
- Enter Domain Name (use the FeatureClass name)
- Set Domain Properties (field type, domain type, etc)
- Enter Code (this is what will populate in your drop down menus) + Description
- Click OK

[image]

Go to the Feature Class

- Right Click
- select Properties
- Select Subtypes
- Select your new subtype from the dropdown menu

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Unfortunately, this is exactly the workflow I've been engaging with up to this point. Reaching out to the Feature Class Properties continues to result in a greyed-out Subtype Field menu.

Comment: what field types are you using? the subtype must be a long or short integer field. if not it will not work. take a look at the [Creating Subtypes](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/creating_subtypes.htm) article from version 9.3 in the Tips section

Comment: Ahhh, apprecitate it. Seems I need a license lmao. ESRI lol http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/c1adc27b-fcc6-4a21-ada0-85a6f16f909f.htm